# Compute Shader Invocations writing conflict

Tags: opengl, compute-shader

I'm doing some work with compute shaders, and I've noticed that if two invocations write to the same location on a texture using `imageStore`, you get a flickering effect when the texture is rendered since access speeds are not guaranteed, and so sometimes one invocation gets there last and sometimes its the other one. I would like my final colour value to be, say, the value with the highest value of red. Is there a way for me to determine that within the shader?

I think there was some confusion, so I'll just give some more info. I'm working with data that I've bound on the CPU as `GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE`, and I access it using

`layout (r8, binding = 0) uniform image3D visualTexture;`

At this stage, I simply just want to stop the flickering, ie, some shader invocation takes preference over the others. The highest value would be ideal, but I want this to be fast.

Comment: Maybe you can use atomic operations?
Or maybe barrier can be helpful as well

Comment: I did think about that, but my problem is that there's only 1 write operation, and I don't think writing can be done atomically.

Comment: So I was partially right. The atomic operations will only work on 32 bit images, whereas the images I'm using are 8-bit. Will this be an issue?

Comment: If you are using three / four chanels images, you could transform values from 4 x 8 to 32 bits images.

Comment: No, I'm single channel, `gl_R8` is my encoding scheme

Comment: I don't know exactly what you are doing, but you can not have mutex or something like that on GPU (it will be really poor for performances). However, maybe there is a possibility using shared variable (if your algorithm can use it), or I think you will must be transform your gl_r8 inside a gl_re32ui :/

Answer (score 1):

[Image atomic operations](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Image_Load_Store#Atomic_operations) are only permitted for single-channel, 32-bit formats (integers and float). So just change your data to use 32-bit integers, rather than 8-bit integers, and use `imageAtomicMax` to set values into the image.

You could just use the 32-bit integer buffer as an intermediary, with a post-process that reads the 32-bit data and writes out to an 8-bit buffer.

Comment: To complete this answer, here is an explanation on how to build such linked list : http://developer.amd.com/wordpress/media/2013/06/2041_final.pdf

Comment: Sorry, I've made it a little more clear what I have. I'm working with a single channel, and I've bound it on the CPU as a `GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE`, if that helps things at all

Comment: @irishMTS: Well, make it a 32-bit integer, and you can use `imageAtomicMax`, like I said ;) Answer updated.

Comment: Okay, that's all well and good, but how do I go about converting to a 32 bit integer from an 8 bit float?